# PHP Query Parameter Not Passing to products.php from index.php"

Tags: php

I'm encountering an issue with passing query parameters from index.php to products.php in a simple PHP web application. Here's the code I'm using:

**index.php:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="products.php?category=laptops">laptops</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="products.php?category=phones">phones</a></li>
</ul>
```

**products.php:**

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
        $selectedCategory = $_GET['category'];
        echo "The category from the clicked link is: " . $selectedCategory;
    } else {
        echo "No category was passed.";
    }
?>
```

The expected behavior is that when I click on a link in index.php, it should take me to products.php with the selected category as a query parameter, and products.php should display `"The category from the clicked link is: [selectedCategory]"` if the category query parameter is set, or `"No category was passed"` if it's not set. Currently it always shows `"No category was passed"`

PHP appears to work properly because index.php has the following code which works without problems:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "Admin";
    $database = "testdata";
    $MK = "";
    
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE category = 'laptops'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        
            $MK = $MK . "
            <div class='col'>
                <div class='card h-100'>
                    <div class='card-header text-capitalize'>" . $row["category"] . "</div>
                    <img src='img/testimg.png' class='card-img-top mt-3' alt='...'>
                    
                    <div class='card-body'>
                        <h5 class='card-title mk-truncate-2'>" . $row["name"] . "</h5> 
                        <div class=''><p class='mk-truncate-2'>" . $row["description"] . "</p></div>               
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class='card-footer p-0'>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-sm pt-3'>€ " . $row["price"] . "</div>
                            <div class='col-sm border-start p-2'>
                                <small class='text-muted'>
                                    <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>Buy</a>
                                </small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>";
        }
        
    } else {
        echo "No records found with category 'a'";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

• I work in Visual Studio Code
• Both index.php and products.php are in the same directory.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: What do  `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` and `var_dump($_GET);` output? What URL is shown in the browser? Which web server do you use and how is it configured?

Comment: enable error reporting in PHP to see if any errors or warnings are being generated,you can do this by adding the following code at the beginning of your PHP files: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: the url shown in the browser: http://127.0.0.1:5500/products.php?category=laptops    `var_dump($_GET)` results in:`array(0) { }`    echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] results in an error:`stderr: PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "QUERY_STRING" in C:\Users\...\products.php on line 9'

Comment: Have you tried this same code with a proper webserver rather than the built-in server within Visual Studio?

Comment: @Freeman adding the error_reporting code did not yield anything

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius excuse my ignorance, I am new to PHP. I've got XAMPP running on the background, if that is what you mean?

Comment: The query is not any kind of dynamic. `$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE category = 'laptops'";`

Comment: @MarkusZeller I know it isn't. I didn't get to that part yet. First I need to solve the issue described above

Comment: You may have XAMPP running but are you _using_ it? `127.0.0.1:5500` doesn't look like the standard URL you'd get with Apache, unless you've reconfigured it? It does look like PHP is executing, hence the dump messages and errors etc. But it's baffling...I can't reproduce your error, and your HTML and PHP code look right in terms of sending and capturing the  URL parameter.

Comment: Turned out that I hadn't  stored the `WebShop` folder in the correct `xampp` directory. thank you for your suggestions!